# Getting list of commands using regex

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I have list of commands where some are having parameters which I need to skip before executing them.

- show abc(h2) xyz
- show abc(h2) xyz opq(h1)
- show abc(h2) xyz <32>
- show abc(a,l) xyz [<32>] opq
- show abc

Ultimately, the list has different combinations of ( ), <>, [] with plain text commands.
I want to separate out all other commands from plain commands like "show abc".

Processing needed on commands :-

```
(h1), (h2), (a,l) are to be discarded
<32> - is to be replaced with any ip address
[<32>] - is to be replaced with any integer digit
```

I tried following but resultant file was empty :-

```
cat show-cmd.txt | grep "<|(|[" > hard-cmd.txt
```

How can I get the result file which has no plain commands using regex?

Desired output file :-

```
show abc xyz
show abc xyz opq
show abc xyz 1.1.1.1
show abc xyz 2 opq
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `grep` followed by `sed`

```
grep '[(<\[]' file | sed -e 's/\[<32>\]/2/g' -e 's/<32>/1.1.1.1/g' -e 's/([^)]*)//g'
```

Output:

```
show abc xyz
show abc xyz opq
show abc xyz 1.1.1.1
show abc xyz 2 opq
```

Please note that order of `s///g` command matters in your case.

Also try avoiding redundant use of `cat`

Answer (score 0):

```
cat show-cmd.txt | grep "[\[\(\<]" > hard-cmd.txt
```

This should work. The opening and closing square brackets [] mean that only one of the options need to be present. Then the further brackets that you want to search for are provided and escaped by a .

Hope this helps.
Pulkit